# "Have been" OR "Had been"?

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

> I have been to Iceland recently.

OR

> I had been to Iceland recently.

What is the difference between the two and which seems correct ?

Comment: They're correct in different circumstances. Also, these constructions are asked about very often; look them up under "present perfect" and "past perfect" (or "pluperfect").

Comment: Can you tell us where you found these sentences? Please use the **[edit]** link to tell us more about your question. Without more information, it is difficult for us to provide a useful answer.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I found these questions in a English book which says to fill up the sentence with either "have been" or "had been". But, hey have given answer "had been" . That's where i am confused as I think "have been " is right here .

Comment: Please use the **[edit]** link to tell us more about these sentences. Try to provide the entire question. Without that, we can't help you, because neither sentence is "incorrect."

Comment: You should be able to find an answer in the [Canonical Post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are both correct, but it depends on the context.

For example, if your time frame for answering the question includes the present, then

> Have you been to Iceland?
>   Yes, I **have** been to Iceland.

your *current state* of having been to Iceland continues to the *present*.

However, if the time reference is in the past

> Did you go to Iceland before [Grímsvötn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_eruption_of_Gr%C3%ADmsv%C3%B6tn)?
>   Yes, I **had been** to Iceland before the eruption.

Comment: In the second example, you may also choose to use simple past tense as the sequence of the events is very clear.